# What is $\frac{\partial\left( F^{T}F\right)}{\partial F}$ in tensor notation?

Tags: analysis, tensors

In index notation, it my calculations are correct the result should be $$\left(\frac{\partial \left(F^{T}F\right)}{\partial F}\right)_{ijkl} = \frac{\partial\left( F_{mi}F_{mj}\right)}{\partial F_{kl}} = F_{mi}\frac{\partial F_{mj}}{\partial F_{kl}} + F_{mj}\frac{\partial F_{mi}}{\partial F_{kl}} = F_{mi}\delta_{mk}\delta_{jl}+F_{mj}\delta_{mk}\delta_{il} = F_{ki}\delta_{jl}+F_{kj}\delta_{il}.$$

I need to add this to some FEM code that uses tensor notation all the way through, so if possible I'd like to have this in tensor notation too, but I have no idea if, or how, this could be written out. It doesn't look like any combination of index notation that I could find in the definitions.

(Just to be clear, by "tensor notation" I mean things like $F\otimes I^T+F^T\otimes I$, for example.)

Comment: I see what the issue is. You want to write the right-hand side in a way that is "readable" by a finite element software. The equation you wrote is correct. Without knowing more about what is readable by the software I cannot help much. I just can remark that there are often equivalent ways to rewrite something, sometimes by "flattening" multi-dimensional arrays and/or doing other tricks.

Comment: @Malkoun It's readable in the current form too, I can always just wrap a few loops into each other and calculate it "manually". I'd just prefer tensor notation to fit the rest of the code, and maybe learn something about how to figure out these things in the process.

Comment: @Malkoun It's the deal.II library in C++. I guess before I go and explicitely permute indices I might as well do it manually. Just thought since the index result is so compact and elegant, there has to be an elegant version in tensor notation. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I understand. Some people in differential geometry for example take a lot of care in establishing notation in a coordinate-free manner. This is good of course, but in some cases, using indices is the easiest way to explain what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note the two conventions:

1. $A⊗B = (A_{ik}B_{jl})_{ij,kl} ↭ AXB^ = (A⊗B)⋅X ↭ \frac{ AXB^}{ X}=A⊗B$
2. $A⊗B = (A_{jl}B_{ik})_{ij,kl} ↭ AXB^ = (B⊗A)⋅X ↭ \frac{ AXB^}{ X}=B⊗A$

For example, [matrixcalulus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) uses (2). I'll be using (1). So let $F$ be $m×n$, then:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{ F'F}{F} 
&= \frac{\partial F'F}{\partial (F', F)} ⋅ \frac{\partial(F', F)}{\partial F}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix} _n⊗F' & F'⊗_n \end{bmatrix}⋅\begin{bmatrix} _{m, n} \\ _{m, n} \end{bmatrix}
\\&= (_n⊗F')⋅_{m, n} + (F'⊗_n)⋅_{m, n}
\\&= _{n, n}⋅(F'⊗_n) + _{n, n}⋅(F'⊗_n) 
\\&= (_{n, n} + _{n, n})⋅(F'⊗_n)
\end{aligned}$$

In particular the directional (Gâteaux-) derivative is given by:

$$
f(F)⋅H 
= (_{n, n} + _{n, n})⋅(F'⊗_n)⋅H 
= (_{n, n} + _{n, n})⋅F'H
= H'F + F'H
$$

Which agrees with the direct way of computing it via $\frac{ f(F+εH)}{ε}\big|_{ε=0}$.

But let me explain the details step by step:

1. In this context "$⋅$" generally does not mean matrix multiplication, but appropriate tensor contraction. For the 4D tensors involved here, typically $A⋅B = (∑_{kl} A_{ij, kl}B_{kl, mn})_{ij, mn}$ which is really just regular old matrix multiplication but with multi-indices.

   - In particular, $(A⊗B)⋅(C⊗D)=(AC⊗BD)$ when dimensions match.
2. $_{m, n} = (δ_{ik}δ_{jl})_{ij, kl} = _m ⊗ _n$ is the **identity tensor** of shape $(m×n, m×n)$.

   - If $A$ is $m×n$ and $B$ is $m'×n'$ then $_{m, m'}·(A ⊗ B) = A ⊗ B = (A ⊗ B)·_{n, n'}$
3. $_{m, n} = (δ_{il}δ_{kj})_{ij, kl}$ is the **transpose tensor** of shape $(n×m, m×n)$.

   - It cannot be written as a pure tensor of the form $A⊗B$.
   - This follows from $A^ = ∑_{mn} (e_me_n^) A (e_me_n^) = ∑_{mn} (E_{mn} ⊗ E_{nm})⋅A = _{m, n}⋅A$
   - I.e. $∑_{mn} (E_{mn} ⊗ E_{nm}) = \sum_{mn}(δ_{im}δ_{kn}δ_{nj}δ_{ml})_{ij, kl} = (δ_{il}δ_{kj})_{ij, kl} = _{m, n}$
   - It satisfies $_{m, n}^ = _{n, m}$, where $(A⊗B)^ = (A^⊗B^)$ is the transpose (for tensors)
   - If $A$ is $m×n$ and $B$ is $m'×n'$ then $_{m, m'}·(A ⊗ B) = (B⊗A)·_{n, n'}$

---

### Source Code Demo

In python, using https://github.com/google/jax for automatic jacobian computation.

```
import jax
import numpy as np

def otimes(A, B):
    """Tensor-product A ⊗ B = (Aᵢₖ·Bⱼₗ)ᵢⱼ,ₖₗ"""
    assert A.ndim==2 and B.ndim==2
    return np.einsum('ij,kl -> ikjl', A, B)



def II(m,n):
    """Identity tensor (ₘ,ₙ)ᵢⱼ,ₖₗ = (δᵢₖ·δⱼₗ)ᵢⱼ,ₖₗ = (ₘ ⊗ ₙ)ᵢⱼ,ₖₗ"""
    I = np.zeros( (m, n, m, n) )
    for i, j, k, l in np.ndindex(I.shape):
        if i==k and j==l:
            I[i,j,k,l] = 1
    return I

def TT(m,n):
    """Transpose tensor (ₘ,ₙ)ᵢⱼₖₗ = (δᵢₗ·δₖⱼ)ᵢⱼₖₗ"""
    T = np.zeros( (n, m, m, n) )
    for i, j, k, l in np.ndindex(T.shape):
        if i==l and j==k:
            T[i,j,k,l] = 1
    return T

def f(X):
    return X.T @ X

g = jax.jacfwd(f)

def g_manual_intermediate(X):
    l = np.tensordot(otimes(np.eye(n), X.T), TT(m,n))
    r = np.tensordot(otimes(X.T, np.eye(n)), II(m,n))
    return l+r

def g_manual(X):
    m, n = X.shape    
    return np.tensordot(TT(n,n) + II(n,n), otimes(X.T, np.eye(n)))

m,n = 5,4
X = np.random.randn(5,4)

assert (g(X) == g_manual_intermediate(X)).all()
assert (g(X) == g_manual(X)).all()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just perfect!